# Finding talon leader

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have a problem maybe one of you guys can help me out I completed Priority: Palaven and united the three mercenary factions under Aria’s rule. I'm supposed to get an email from Aria saying "Omega: It’s Time." but I haven't received anything yet, except from the first mail she sends to meet up. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should add what platform you are playing this on.

Comment: my only suggestion would be to see if there is any other pending thing that aria is involved in. Also go back over the specifics, see if there is anything you have missed?